# Is realm closing database after unsubscription

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

If I do something like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Subscription subscription = realm.where(Person.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
    .filter(persons.isLoaded)
    .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();

... 

subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Will `unsubscribe()` internally call `realm.close()` or do I have to call that manually?

Comment: I think your code here is supposed to give you `IllegalStateException: Realm access from a different thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will unsubscribe() internally call realm.close() or do I have to call that manually?

It will not close the realm for you, you have to do that manually.

You can have multiple subscriptions for a single realm instance, unsubscribing any of those subscriptions should not close the realm because you might still want to use the other subscriptions.

Also see the [RxJava example project](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/rxJavaExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/rxjava/gotchas/GotchasActivity.java) provided by Realm.

Also note that Subscription is a RxJava class, not a Realm class. It doesn't even know you are using Realm, hence it would be strange if it closed the realm.

Comment: thanks ... too bad ... would like to avoid calling `reaml.close()` in `Activity.onDestroy()` ...

Comment: @sockeqwe why? That is the recommended approach

Comment: Maybe I have missunderstood something, but I would like to be android lifecycle unaware ... I think I will find some workaround to be rx subscription lifecycle aware rather then android lifecycle aware

Comment: @sockeqwe that's fine. As long as you close a realm when you're done with  it